# Javascript Looping With Sum Operation

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to Loop a NAFAG field and sum every NAFAG field with a scheme like this. Every time I repeat the NAFAG sum, the result should be added to the KNAFA field

- 0 + -30000 results to the 2nd row KNAFA field
- 0 + -30000 + -30000 results to the 3rd row KNAFA field
- 0 + -30000 + -30000 + -30000 results to the 4th row KNAFA field
- 0 + -30000 + -30000 + -30000 + -30000 results to the 5th row KNAFA field

[image]

can anyone help me with this loop.

Comment: Give me a minimum of executable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope my code help you.

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>KNAFA</th>
    <th>NAFAG</th>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
let nafag = [0, -3000, -3000,-3000,-3000,-3000, -3000];
let sum = 0;
for (const elem of nafag) {
    sum += elem;
  let elements = "<tr><td>" + sum + "</td><td>" + elem + "</td></tr>";
  var parent_tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
 
  var new_tr = document.createElement('tr');
  new_tr.innerHTML = elements;
  parent_tbody[0].appendChild(new_tr);
}
```

**Result**

| KNAFA | NAFAG |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| -3000 | -3000 |
| -6000 | -3000 |
| -9000 | -3000 |
| -12000 | -3000 |
| -15000 | -3000 |
| -18000 | -3000 |

Comment: How do you add a table to an answer?

Comment: try this. |KNAFA| NAFAG|
|-|-|
|0|0|
|-3000|-3000|